# Set product's category based on its current category children

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category-tree

I have a lot of products on database, and every single one has a single category asociated, now I want to assign every category parent linked with its current category children. For example, in the case of sunglasses, I would like to associate the "Accesories" categories to it, because the current category of sunglasses is "Eyewear", because is the category child of "Accessories". I could do this with 5 or 10 products, but I have hundreds, so I want to do this by code, my little problem now is I can't identify the table with the category parent-children association.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table I was looking for is `catalog_category_entity`. The table has a `parent_id` field (a self referencing foreign key) and a `path` field, which has its complete category tree separated by slashes. This is all the information I need in order to write my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can find category parent-children association in table `catalog_category_entity` in column `path`. It show full category tree path: category ids joined by `/` delimeter.

At screenshots you can find `Living Room` category with id `22`. At the first screen tree in admin side. And at the second path in db table.

[image: Category path]
[image: DB structure]